# Are these rings Artinian? Are the composition series correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, artinian

I just want to check whether my solutions are right. The rings are $$\mathbb{Z}_{75}\text{ and } \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{((x-2)^2)}$$
The first one is finite so it is Artinian and the second is a finite dimensional algebra over an Artinian ring, so it is Artinian. For the composition series, I picked
$$0<(25)<(5)< \mathbb{Z}_{75}$$
and
$$0< \frac{(x-2)}{((x-2)^2)}< \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{((x-2)^2)}$$
Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct!${}{}{}$